# Weird thing with selenium test (python) on angular js based UI

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, webdriver

We are testing a web application based on angular js. I have encountered it twice now. this time I need to click a dropdown embedded in a link tag . I can manually manipulate it with ipython, but once it run in script, the dropdown popup will not appear as what I can do it with the terminal.

Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: What error message do you get in the script? NoSuchElement? ElementNotVisible? Full traceback would be good.

Comment: there is no error actually, the element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comment "there is no error actually, the element is clicked", then I would suspect that the script is running fast enough to click the element before the JavaScript actions have been bound to the event. You can verify this by adding a

```
import time
time.sleep(4)
```

If the action works when there is a deliberate pause then you can be quite sure that it is a race condition between the JavaScript being bound and Selenium clicking the element.

How you deal with this is up to you. You could mark the DOM in some way when the events had been bound. That's a technique I've used in the past.

You could execute a bit of JavaScript in a loop that returned some information about the global state of the page, and use that to decide when the page was ready to interact with.